# Extract JSON from Facebook Marketing API using XPATH in Talend

Tags: json, facebook, xpath, talend

currently I am extracting data from the Facebook Marketing API.
I am Using an XPATH query in Talend Studio for the JSON i get via the API.

Since this is my first Job with JSON and XPATH I need some help with the following extraction:

At first a part of my JSON:

```
{
  "data": [
    {
      .
      .
      .
      "adsets": {
        "data": [
          {
           .
           .
           .
            "targeting": {
              "age_max": 60,
              "age_min": 18,
              "geo_locations": {
                "countries": [
                  "DE"
                ]
              },
              "facebook_positions": [
                "feed",
                "right_hand_column"
              ],
.
.
.
```

Now i want to extract from "facebook_positions" with XPATH:

"/data/adsets/data/targeting/facebook_positions"

with that XPATH query I only get "feed" as my result but I need  "feed,right_hand_column" since there are no keys to the values like ' "age_max": 60' I am not able to extract the correct path.

Thanks in advance for your help!

Best Regards
CoGe

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried :-

```
//facebook_positions
```

OR

`//facebook_positions[1]` -> feed

`//facebook_positions[2]` -> right_hand_column

Example :-

Open below URL:

http://www.jsonquerytool.com/

```
{
    "data": [{
        "adsets": {
            "data": [{

                "targeting": {
                    "age_max": 60,
                    "age_min": 18,
                    "geo_locations": {
                        "countries": [
                            "DE"
                        ]
                    },
                    "facebook_positions": [
                        "feed",
                        "right_hand_column"
                    ]
                }
            }]
        }
    }]
}
```

Select Query for JSON as :-

Xpath for JSon

put the query as :-

//facebook_positions

Click on Run

[image]

Comment: I tried both but still get only "feed" as result. Additionally "(//facebook_positions)[1]" throws me an exception in Talend since it doesnt like a "(" in an XPATH query. Instead I tried "//facebook_positions[1]" but also got only "feed" as result

Comment: Try //facebook_positions[2]  ... the array postion should return you right_hand_column

Comment: Thank you, that worked! But what if I got a non specific amount of results and I want to get all together (get the whole array), is it possible?

Comment: Using script you can check the length of size of the object and iterate each value till the size of length ends

Comment: so there is no flag to add to the XPATH query to get the whole array like " /facebook_positions[*] " ?

Comment: I have no idea about talend. If it support some kind of script to be run then you can use iteration to extract all value using length of an array.

Comment: Hey //facebook_positions itself should give you all results

Comment: see the result //facebook_positions itself returns all values in array

Comment: you need to use index if you require any specific value

Comment: thank you. In Talend I had to use another XPATH Loop directly on '/data/adsets/data/targeting/facebook_positions' and as the XPATH Request './.' to iterate in that array